# Iterate XML using groovy

Tags: groovy, iteration

I have a requirement to loop through XML and only pass 3 elements and in the next iteration pick the next 3 from 4 to 16 and so on.

I am controlling the value of counter from outside the script.

I wrote the below code, however it does not works as expected.

```
    <employees>
    <details>
        <id>1</id>
    </details>
    <details>
        <id>2</id>
    </details>
    <details>
        <id>3</id>
    </details>
    <details>
        <id>4</id>
    </details>
    <details>
        <id>5</id>
    </details>
    <details>
        <id>6</id>
    </details>
    <details>
        <id>7</id>
    </details>
    <details>
        <id>8</id>
    </details>
</employees>

       def doc = new XmlSlurper().parseText(body);  
       int count = doc.details.size(); 
       def query = "\$filter=FSE_ID eq '";
       int counter = 1; // this value will come from outside the script.
       int counterLimt = counter + 2;
       int i= counter;
       for (i = counter; i <= counterLimt; i++) {
       doc.details[i].CEE_ID.each{
           if(i==counterLimt){
               query = query+it+"'"; 
           }
           else{
           query = query+it+"' or FSE_ID eq '";  
           i++;
           }
       }
       }
```

expected output is

first run

$filter=FSE_ID eq '1' or FSE_ID eq '2' or FSE_ID eq '3'

next run

$filter=FSE_ID eq '4' or FSE_ID eq '5' or FSE_ID eq '6'

there seems to be some issue with the .each and it does not works as I thought.

Please help.

Thanks
Yatan

Answer (score 0):

I was almost there.

by removing the i++; from inside the .each loop it works.